# Directing the Root Context to the Developer Portal WSO2 on Docker?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i am trying to Directing the Root Context to the Developer Portal on the dockerized version of WSO2, but how i can keep the changes without edit files inside the container ?

I followed this docs:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/customizations/directing-the-root-context-to-the-developer-portal/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you running this without a container orchestration system, then you can mount these configurations to the docker container as volumes.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

If you are using K8s or any container orchestration system, then in K8s you can use configmaps to add these files.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/

In both cases, you are not editing files in the container and simply replace these files.